# How to configure vs code working directory in the launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use goland(same as webstorm/intellij etc)  IDE and in debug configuration there is a place when you can configure `working directory` Now I try to work with VSCODE and I dont find this configuration , after a bit research I find the following json which should handle this but dont find the right place for working directory

e.g. this is my working directory

`/Users/i022226/go/src/myapp`

```
"configurations": [{
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": [],
            "showLog": true
        }
```

In the `launch.json` there is add configuration button and when I type `cwd` I dont get any entry, any idea ?

In this post the `cwd` is under the `option` but I dont find the `option` 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/856

Comment: There is a `launch.json` file...there you should be able to set the `cwd` property...(`cwd` stands for `current working directory`)

Comment: @Hackerman - The json that I put in the question is the launch.json  ;) , I dont see any `cwd` there, any idea?>]

Comment: There are more options available than are shown on one of the default pre-made tasks.  Try typing "cwd" within a task and you will see it prompted.

Comment: @Mark - Try it without success , I dont find the cwd when I click on add configuration on the launch.json

Answer (score 12):

Here's an example `launch.json` to run a Python module in a project subfolder based on [Tals's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47547153/2597913):

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Launch",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "module_source_folder.filename",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/examples/folder_with_test_files",
            "args": ["-f", "input_filename"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that `cwd` must come before `args` or it won't work.

Answer (score 10):

You should add it like following

```
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "debug",
        "cwd": "Your Path",
        "remotePath": "",
        "port": 2345,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "program": "${fileDirname}",
        "env": {},
        "args": [],
        "showLog": true
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't correspond to my case exactly, but the key informations were: the key is `"cwd"`, and one useful variable is `${fileDirname}`...